# JS - Dynamic website form changing URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

I have couple of questions about creating dynamic website. I'm using [MaterializeCSS](http://next.materializecss.com/) and basic JQuery. My main point is making my website dynamically change content in divs based on clicked  or  with some ID and still have "browser history", so you can go back. Is it possible to do this with vanilla JQuery or I need to use [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) or some framework like this?
I already have something written in JQuery, but that's just .Show() and .Hide(), which won't do anything in browser history, which is important to me. Also I would like to show one div (with loading bar), but only when it will be loading, If it's possible.

Thanks for answers

```
<div class="login_box card darken-1">
            <div class="progress"><div class="indeterminate"></div></div>

            <div id="email_block" class="card-content">
                <img class="login_logo" src="./images/svg/logo_text.svg">
                <h1 class="login_header">Log in</h1>
                <div class="mt-4 input-field">
                    <input id="email" class="validate" type="email">
                    <label for="email" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Email</label>
                    <span class="helper-text" data-error="Wrong syntax" data-success=""></span>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-2">
                    <a href="#" class="login_password">Forget your password?</a>
                    <a href="#next" id="next_btn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue accent-2 right">Next</a>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-3 center-align">
                    <a href="#register" id="register_btn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue accent-2 wide_button left">Register</a>
                </div>
                <div class="login_footer center-align mt-1">
                    <a class="waves-effect waves-light red btn wide_button">Sync w/ Google</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="password_block" class="card-content">
                <img class="login_logo" src="./images/svg/logo_text.svg">
                <h1 class="login_header">Log in - Pass</h1>
                <div class="mt-4 input-field">
                    <input id="password" class="validate" type="password">
                    <label for="password" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-2">
                    <a href="#" class="login_password">Forget your password?</a>
                    <a href="#login_next" id="" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue accent-2 right">Next</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="register_block" class="card-content">
                <img class="login_logo" src="./images/svg/logo_text.svg">
                <h1 class="login_header">Register</h1>
                <div class="mt-4 input-field">
                    <input id="email" class="validate" type="email">
                    <label for="email" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Email</label>
                    <span class="helper-text" data-error="Wrong syntax" data-success=""></span>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-2">
                    <a href="#register_next" id="btn_next_register" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue accent-2 right">Next</a>
                    <a class="waves-effect waves-light red btn">W/ Google</a>
                </div>
                <div class="login_footer"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="register_pass_block" class="card-content">
                <img class="login_logo" src="./images/svg/logo_text.svg">
                <h1 class="login_header">Register</h1>
                <div class="mt-4 input-field">
                    <input id="password" class="validate" type="password">
                    <label for="password" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input id="password" class="validate" type="password">
                    <label for="password" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Confirm Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-2">
                    <a href="#confirm_register_next" id="" class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue accent-2 right">Next</a>
                </div>
                <div class="login_footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('.login_box .card-content').not("#email_block").hide();
    $('#next_btn').click(function() {
        $('.login_box .card-content').hide();
        $('#password_block').show();
    });
    $('#register_btn').click(function() {
        $('.login_box .card-content').hide();
        $('#register_block').show();
    });
    $('#btn_next_register').click(function() {
        $('.login_box .card-content').hide();
        $('#register_pass_block').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: @Utkanos I don't think that's what I want :/... There is some PHP code... I would like to happy as simple as possible..